# Machine learning parameter tuning using partitioned benchmark dataset

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, svm, dataset, scikit-learn

I know this will be very basic, however I'm really confused and I would like to understand parameter tuning better.

I'm working on a benchmark dataset that is already partitioned to three splits training, development, and testing and I would like to tune my classifier parameters using GridSearchCV from sklearn. What is the correct partition to tune the parameter? is it the development or the training?

I'v seen researchers in the literature mentioning that they "tuned the parameters using GridSearchCV on the development split" another example is found here https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1617/MLRD/handbook/dataset-splits.pdf , do they mean they trained on the training split then tested on the development split? or do ML practitioners usually mean they perform the GridSearchCV entirely on the development split?

I'd really appreciate a clarification. 
Thanks,